# Difference of time in milliseconds?

Tags: java, hibernate, date, datetime, timestamp

jsp code:

```
String activationkey=request.getParameter("activationkey");   
      System.out.println("key is=="+activationkey);
      CustinfoDao custinfoDao = new CustinfoDaoImpl();
      CustomerInfo cust=custinfoDao.getDateByActivationKey(activationkey);


            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
           //get current date time with Date()
           Date date = new Date();


        Date d1=new Date();
        System.out.println("d1================="+d1.getTime());

        Date d2= cust.getCreatedDate();
        System.out.println("d2================="+d2.getTime());



        long d3=d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();
        System.out.println("d3 is =="+d3);
        long diffHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(d3);
        System.out.println("diff in hours=="+diffHours);
        System.out.println("diff in hours=="+(diffHours<48));


           if(diffHours < 48){

 %>
       <script type="text/javascript">

           window.open("http://bdisys.com/Download/BizViz/BizVizPackage.zip");

       </script>
 <%        
       }
       else{
 %>        
           <div>Your Link has been Expired....</div>
 <%      }

 %>
```

Output:

```
 key is==L2NWL49fx5
d1=================1399901683076
d2=================1399833000000
d3 is ==68683076
diff in hours==19
diff in hours==true
```

I want to get the difference of time in hours between the current date and the date on which user had registered through a form and want to expire the link if the difference is geater than 48 hours
or else want to execute other block of code.but i am not able to get exact time difference.Any help would be appreaciated.

Comment: What is not working? `68683076 / (3600 * 1000)` ~ 19 hours is right.

Comment: @MenoHochschild the current date and the registration date both are same ie; 2014-05-12  why am i getting 19 hours of difference??

Comment: The current date? I assume you speak about d1. Yes, this also contains any time part down to milliseconds. About d2, you seem to live in a timezone with half hour offset (maybe India +05:30) so it represents a full day in that timezone explaining the 6 trailing zero digits. Both d1 and d2 cannot be the same expressed in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i perfectly understood your problem, but it seems to me like `d3` has the exact time difference. So i assume your problem is when you do

`long diffHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(d3);`

you don't get enough precision.

If that's the case, you can juste do

`if (d3 < 48*3600*1000)` to test if `d3` is less than 48 hours in milliseconds.

Hope i understood you question :)

Comment: he current date and the registration date both are same ie; 2014-05-12 why am i getting 19 hours of difference??

Comment: oh sorry, i didn't see the new comments while i was writing my answer.
are you sure that's the case? try replacing `d2` by, say, your `Date date` that you don't use (AFAIK) and see the output. You will then know if your problem is with the time comparison or elsewhere

Comment: @user3463325 if you have a correct output for the comparison when you don't use `cust.getCreatedDate();` but another date you just created, then it means you have a different format for the date you save on creation and the date you use for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

new Date() will return the current time including hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.

custinfoDao.getDateByActivationKey(activationkey)  appears to be returning the time when the record was added.

These times will certainly be different since you are not just comparing dates (YYYY/MM/DD), you are comparing time (YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss) as well.